# Enable IMAP PHP in xampp (windows)

Tags: php, windows, xampp, imap

I am installing a CRM locally and I have a problem with IMAP. I am looking for and find that "extension = imap" must be enabled, but I do it and it remains the same.

Notice that I am using xampp in Windows 10.

[image]

I thank you in advance

Comment: from the *php.ini*  find this line *;extension=php_imap.dll* and remove *semicolon(;)* and restart your xampp server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to configure your php.ini file to enable IMAP extension

Search for the line `;extension=php_imap.dll` and remove semicolon(`;`) and restart your xampp. The line should look like as mentioned below.

`extension=php_imap.dll`

Comment: Where should I search for this ;extension=php_imap.dll can you please share the file path or some instructions please.

Comment: @Harish you can run `phpenmod imap`

Comment: Thank you @VictorPudeyev I'll try - But this was asked 2 years ago. :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

New php version does not have dll anymore.

#### Steps

1. Access your php.init file. [xampp\php\php.init]
2. Remove the semicolon(;)
3. Restart your xampp.

#### Demo

Image: https://prnt.sc/tu6frh

```
;extension=imap -> extension=imap
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file to enable IMAP extension

Search for the line `;extension=imap` and remove semicolon(;) and restart your xampp.

```
extension=imap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
apt install php7.4-imap # or whatever version you have
phpenmod imap
```